# What return value of sequelize when update?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am write API in expressjs with Sequence. But I got problem with return value when update!

I follow a tutorial on internet but it got error when `num=[1]` not `num=1` although updating success!

```js
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  Post.update(req.body, {
    where: { id }
  })
    .then((num) => {
      if (num === 1) {
        res.send({
          message: 'Post was updated successfully.'
        });
      }
      else {
        res.send({
          message: `Cannot update Post with id=${id}. Maybe Post was not found or req.body is empty!`
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: `Error updating Post with id=${id}`
      });
    });
};
```

So, what return value after call update method? and how do I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: you can try to `console.log(num)` and see  what data is returned when data is updated successfully

Answer (score 0):

[The sequelize document of update](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update) is

public static async update(values: object, options: object): Promise<Array<number, number>>

Promise<Array<number, number>>
The promise returns an array with one or two elements. The first element is always the number of affected rows, while the second element is the actual affected rows (only supported in postgres with options.returning true).

So, it will not return only the number. you need to follow the document.

To resolve

```
.then((nums) => {
 const num = nums[0]
 .....
```